# WC_Gateway_Stripe not found in Wordpress - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am trying to build an API for WooCommerce, and I have a problem with building the Pay functionality. The problem is that the `WC_Gateway_Stripe` function is not found and I cannot seem to find it defined anywhere, though I can find it being used in other places.

```
function CodestagePay(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $response       = array();
    $parameters     = [
        'payment_method' => 'stripe',
        'order_id'       => $request->get_param('order_id'),
        'stripe_token'   => $request->get_param('payment_token'),
    ];
    $payment_method = sanitize_text_field( $parameters['payment_method'] );
    $order_id       = sanitize_text_field( $parameters['order_id'] );
    $payment_token  = sanitize_text_field( $parameters['stripe_token'] );
    $error          = new WP_Error();

    if ( empty( $payment_method ) ) {
        $error->add( 400, __( "Payment Method 'payment_method' is required.", 'wc-rest-payment' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }
    if ( empty( $order_id ) ) {
        $error->add( 401, __( "Order ID 'order_id' is required.", 'wc-rest-payment' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    } else if ( wc_get_order($order_id) == false ) {
        $error->add( 402, __( "Order ID 'order_id' is invalid. Order does not exist.", 'wc-rest-payment' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    } else if ( wc_get_order($order_id)->get_status() !== 'pending' ) {
        $error->add( 403, __( "Order status is NOT 'pending', meaning order had already received payment. Multiple payment to the same order is not allowed. ", 'wc-rest-payment' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }   
    if ( empty( $payment_token ) ) {
        $error->add( 404, __( "Payment Token 'payment_token' is required.", 'wc-rest-payment' ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
        return $error;
    }
    
    if ( $payment_method === "stripe" ) {
         $wc_gateway_stripe     = new WC_Gateway_Stripe();
         $_POST['stripe_token'] = $payment_token;
         $payment_result        = $wc_gateway_stripe->process_payment( $order_id );
         if ( $payment_result['result'] === "success" ) {
             $response['code']    = 200;
             $response['message'] = __( "Your Payment was Successful", "wc-rest-payment" );

             $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

             // set order to completed
             if( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {
                 $order->update_status( 'completed' );
             }

         } else {
             return new WP_REST_Response( array("c"), 123 );
             $response['code']    = 401;
             $response['message'] = __( "Please enter valid card details", "wc-rest-payment" );
         }
    } else {
        $response['code'] = 405;
        $response['message'] = __( "Please select an available payment method. Supported payment method can be found at https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-rest-payment/#description", "wc-rest-payment" );
    }

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 123 );
}
```